# C# UI not printing out strings generated from PowerShell commands?

Tags: c#, powershell, active-directory, office365

I'm trying to create a UI executable using C# that runs PowerShell commands to return a list of dynamic distribution groups from an active directory. These dynamic distribution groups are to go into a dropdown menu.
The problem that I'm running into is that the objects returned from the PowerShell script are unable to be converted into strings. When I display the results of the function in the UI, it shows up as "System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[System.Management.Automation.PSObject]". When I looked this up, it's apparently a type of powershell object, which I think is telling me that C# receives the value but is not interpreting it correctly.
How do I convert the values contained within the powershell object into strings that can be printed onto the C# UI?

This is the code that I used to call the Powershell script from within the C# program:

```
            Runspace? runningspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();

            Collection<PSObject> result = new Collection<PSObject>();
            
            
            PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();
                runningspace.Open();
                powershell.Runspace = runningspace;

                System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader("script.ps1");
                powershell.AddScript(sr.ReadToEnd());

                result = powershell.Invoke();
                ResultBox.Text = Convert.ToString(result);

                sr.Close();
                sr.Dispose();
```

This part of the code is not generating any items in the DropDownMenu:

```
                 foreach (PSObject obj in result)   
                 {              
                    DropDownMenu.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(obj));              
                  }
```

This is the Powershell script I'm running (minus code to log into the active directory I'm accessing):

```
$groups = Get-DynamicDistributionGroup
return Write-Output $groups
```

NOTE: I created the UI on Visual Studio using the WPF Application template. Not sure if that will help, but I figured I should give as much information as may be helpful.

Comment: Is there a reason you're calling PowerShell to do this instead of doing it all in C#?

Comment: I'm trying to access the members of a dynamic distribution group, and the commands for that using PowerShell are readily available. Also, I'm trying to make the application more secure by making the UI code separate from the code that accesses the server.

Comment: You’re basically calling the ```ToString``` method on an instance of the type ```System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<System.Management.Automation.PSObject>``` - the default behaviour is to return the name of the type. If you want more sophisticated output you’ll need to serialise it yourself in your C# code and output that instead. As for what the code to do that would be, it depends on what you want the output to look like…

Comment: Anything you can do in PowerShell you can do in C# easier. If you show the PowerShell script, someone can show you how to do it in C#. If you want to keep UI and AD code separate, you can just put them in different classes.

Comment: @GabrielLuci I'm literally just running those two lines of PowerShell script, on top of two lines to log into the AD.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. This question has code that will look for all dynamic DLs and get the query used for each group: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53431322/1202807

Comment: And this answer has code showing how to use the query found in the `msExchDynamicDLFilter` attribute to perform the query to find the members of that group: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12644677/1202807

Comment: @mclayton would using result.ToString(); yield the same result?

Comment: The quickest way to find out is to try it and see what happens. My guess is “yes”…

Comment: @GabrielLuci in the code from your first link, what object type is DomName? It isn't clear to me, and the only sources I can find with code with the variable DomName are the same question from other websites/in other languages.

Comment: @PoeAnLu It's the domain name. In that example they use the distinguished name of the domain (e.g. `DC=example,DC=com`), but you can use the DNS name too (`example.com`). And the `searchRoot` is built in a strange way. It can just be `new DirectoryEntry("GC://example.com")`. And the `group` variable is unused and not needed.